# Problem using the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I'm working on the following problem:

> Using Central Limit Theorem, compute the number of people to poll in a
>   public opinion survey to estimate the fraction of the population that
>   will vote in favor of a proposition within $\alpha$ percent, with
>   probability at least $1 - \beta$.

I'm a bit confused on how the Central Limit Theorem can be applied to this problem. The Central Limit Theorem has to do with a distribution of i.i.d. random variables converging to a normal distribution. I don't see how to pose this problem in a way that will allow me to make use of the theorem. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: "vote in favor of a proposition within α percent" - seems a little unclear what that means. I would have considered a vote to be either yes/no.